# Send array data to server in android

Tags: android

I have code to send data phone from contact in android. As we know that many data in phone contact in android. I have code to get data from phone contact and show as listview like this

```
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

                int row = cursor.getCount();
                friend_item = new MenuItem [row];
                int i=0;
                while(cursor.moveToNext()){
                    nama = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
                    phone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    friend_item[i] = new MenuItem(nama,phone);
                    i++;
                }

List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone", mPhoneNumber));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("friend", phone));

                // getting JSON string from URL
                JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(Constants.url_phone_contact, "POST", params);
                 // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
                Log.d("All Friend: ", json.toString());

                try {                    
                    friend = json.getJSONArray("friend");
                    friend_item = new MenuItem[friend.length()]; 
                     // looping through All Products
                    for (int a = 0; a < friend.length(); a++) {
                    JSONObject c = friend.getJSONObject(i); 

                    //Storing each json item in variable
                    String phone_friend= c.getString(TAG_PHONE);

                    friend_item[i] = new MenuItem(nama, phone_friend);

                     // creating new HashMap
                     HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                     // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                   map.put("nama", nama);
                   map.put("phone", phone_friend);

                   // adding HashList to ArrayList
                      friendList.add(map);
                   }


              } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

              }             

        return null;

        }
```

in `params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("friend", phone));`

friend is data array , array from [phone_contact] . So how I can send data array and String "mPhoneNumber" to server in android?? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can send data to server like this.

```
for(int i=0;i<unique_id.length;i++)
{
     params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("unique_id[]",unique_id[i]));
}
```

You need to take for loop for getting array value and assign data to namevaluepairs.

Comment: Iam new in android , how to assign data like this to namevaluepairs?